# How to use CSS function instead of LESS function?

Tags: css, less

I'm using LESS for a project and I'm trying to use the `saturate()` method of the CSS `filter` property (which takes a decimal or percent as an argument), however I can't get it working because LESS is trying to compile it using its own `saturate()` method, which takes a color as the argument.

Is there a way I can instruct the LESS compiler to treat the `saturate()` method as the vanilla CSS version, instead of the LESS version?

Comment: What Less compiler do you use? The [reference one](https://github.com/less/less.js) (version 1.5.x and higher) can perfectly distinguish between either form by their parameters (e.g. `saturate(#123, 50%);` -> built-in function and `saturate(50%);`-> CSS function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution, I needed to escape both the outer property value as well as the inner expression inside the parentheses.

```
-webkit-filter: ~"saturate(~"50%")";
```

Answer (score 2):

You do it kind of like this:

```
-webkit-filter: ~"saturate(" 50% ~")";
```

Cheers!